# self adjusting layout using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
* {
 border: none;
 font-family: monospace;
}
html, body {height: 100%;}
body {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 10px;
}
.container {
 background: #eee;
 box-shadow: 0 10px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,.45);
 margin: auto;
 width: 500px; 
 padding: 30px 20px 20px;
}

/* main css starts here */

.row {
 display: flex;
 margin-bottom: 10px
}

input {
 flex: 1;
 padding: 2px 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 border: dotted 1px #bbb;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background: #fefefe
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <label>hey ya!</label>
    <input/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>how are you?</label>
    <input/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>i am fine</label>
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want all labels to have same width, where width is *exactly* equal to the content width of widest label. I want layout to automatically adjust all label width.

Right now, you can see the width of labels is different. If I want same width label then I have to either add a `flex-basis` property to label items or give them a `min-width` value. I dont want to do either of them as then I have to manually first check the width of widest label element and layout will break if I change letter spacing or choose some wide font.

In XUL there is a `vbox` element which helps to make such kind of layout and in html I guess table can be used to do so but I am looking for a flexbox solution.

Comment: Can't be done with flexbox - flex items can only relate to items that are on the same row as them, not to items that are on other rows. If you want all the labels to be the same width, then you need to set it manually.

Comment: You're looking for `display: table`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol can you post an example?

Comment: @adam actually the font that I have to use is the default OS font. On different OS that default font changes. On Ubuntu, default font is Ubuntu which is a lot wider in comparison to Roboto(my linux distro default font). I can't target all OS if I have to set it manually. Layout will break on some os.

Comment: @ArshadKhan - then as Niet said, use `display: table` - it does **exactly** what you want.

Comment: @Adam   here is a pen - https://codepen.io/arshdkhn1/pen/eRVQzz Can you tell how do i make sure `col1` width is equal to width of widest label element. Right now I have assigned it a static width of `100px`.

Comment: This is not possible with Flexbox, unless you change the markup a little. If you also expect the label text to wrap, you won't be able to use Flexbox at all, then as mentioned CSS Table, or CSS Grid is your options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Niet pointed out, use `display: table`

```css
* {
 border: none;
 font-family: monospace;
}
html, body {height: 100%;}
body {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 10px;
}
.container {
  display: table;
 background: #eee;
 box-shadow: 0 10px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,.45);
 margin: auto;
 padding: 30px 20px 20px;
}

/* main css starts here */

.row {
  display: table-row;
 margin-bottom: 10px
}

label {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}

input {
 padding: 2px 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 border: dotted 1px #bbb;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background: #fefefe
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <label>hey ya!</label>
    <input/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>how are you?</label>
    <input/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>i am fine</label>
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why label are wider than `contentWidth of howareyou? label` + `10px`(padding)? I want them exactly to be equal to the contentWidth + padding/margin.

Comment: @ArshadKhan - There is a left margin on the input of 10px (from your code)

Comment: nope. I dont think that's because of left margin. https://imagebin.ca/v/3WzAVOUdqD9M

Comment: @ArshadKhan `margin` doesn't work on table cells. You have to wrap the label and input to be able to use it.

Comment: @LGSon ok, but I am wondering why extra whitespace is being take by label element. It is not exacttly equal to the width of 2nd label(widest) element. margin is not issue now.

Comment: @ArshadKhan The input has a left margin and the label has a 5px padding. Remove those and set a background to the label and you'll see their size and that it works